# jquery json parsing two codes one working other not

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, rest, jsonp

I have following codes for parsing jason response from the server. I include also the respective responses. The first codes works but the second does not. Can you give a hint? Thanks.
First code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't want to iterate over the content of `bibliographic-data` but just get one property from it

replace this

```
$.each(oData['ops:world-patent-data']['exchange-documents']['bibliographic-data'],
    function(iIndex, mValue) {
         console.log(mValue['publication-reference'])
    }
);
```

with that:

```
console.log(oData['ops:world-patent-data']['exchange-documents']['bibliographic-data']['publication-reference']);
```

get doc-number:

```
console.log(oData['ops:world-patent-data']['exchange-documents']['bibliographic-data']['publication-reference']['document-id'][0]['doc-number']);
```

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion works. Though if I replace with: console.log(oData['ops:world-patent-data']['exchange-documents']['exchange-document']['bibliographic-data']['publication-reference']['doc-number)']);  I receive undefined message, how can I reach to doc-number property??.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one element in the structure if I read this properly:

```
ops:world-patent-data.exchange-documents.exchange-document.bibliographic-data.publication-reference
```

so insert in `['exchange-document']`

Put this in a fiddle document and see if this helps you: http://jsfiddle.net/pfJjG/1/

```
var iam = {
    "ops:world-patent-data": {
        "@xmlns": {
            "ops": "http://ops.epo.org",
            "$": "http://www.epo.org/exchange",
            "ccd": "http://www.epo.org/ccd",
            "xlink": "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        },
        "ops:meta": {
            "@name": "elapsed-time",
            "@value": "31"
        },
        "exchange-documents": {
            "exchange-document": {
                "@system": "ops.epo.org",
                "@family-id": "35636806",
                "@country": "EP",
                "@doc-number": "1814517",
                "@kind": "A1",
                "bibliographic-data": {
                    "publication-reference": {
                        "document-id": [
                            {
                            "@document-id-type": "docdb",
                            "country": {
                                "$": "EP"
                            },
                            "doc-number": {
                                "$": "1814517"
                            },
                            "kind": {
                                "$": "A1"
                            },
                            "date": {
                                "$": "20070808"
                            }},
                        {
                            "@document-id-type": "epodoc",
                            "doc-number": {
                                "$": "EP1814517"
                            },
                            "date": {
                                "$": "20070808"
                            }}
                        ]
                    },
                    "classifications-ipcr": {
                        "classification-ipcr": [
                            {
                            "@sequence": "1",
                            "text": {
                                "$": "A61K   9/    08            A I"
                            }},
                        {
                            "@sequence": "2",
                            "text": {
                                "$": "A61K  31/    19            A I"
                            }},
                        {
                            "@sequence": "3",
                            "text": {
                                "$": "A61K  31/   216            A I"
                            }},
                        {
                            "@sequence": "4",
                            "text": {
                                "$": "A61K  47/    00            A I"
                            }}]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
$('#me').text(iam["ops:world-patent-data"]["exchange-documents"]["exchange-document"]["bibliographic-data"]["publication-reference"]["document-id"][0]["doc-number"].$);
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I receive undefined message in the console.